# Detecting Available Qualities of YouTube Videos

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm writing a [Boxee](http://www.boxee.tv) app that makes use of YouTube videos and I want to be able to display the highest quality version available.  I was looking through the YouTube API, but I can't seem to find a way to detect if 720p and/or 1080p versions of the video are available.

Does anyone know how to do this?  I'm already using their Data API to collection information about the video, but there doesn't seem to be anything in the payload about different qualities consumable on the web: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/NWHfY_lvKIQ

I could just hard code fmt=22 and let it default to a lesser quality version, but then I miss out on 1080p (fmt=387).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information isn't available through the API, but can be queried and changed via JavaScript after the page has loaded (if you embed a video for example).

http://groups.google.com/group/youtube-api-gdata/browse_thread/thread/da4344cc66959ecc